# data:image/jpg;base64 open and resize/zoom-out in new tab

Tags: html, css

I have a preview button for an `input type=file` element which opens the selected image on a new tab:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + myImageDataUrl;

var w = window.open("");
w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
```

The problem is that images that exceed browser's height and width will display in full size requiring the user to use the window's scroll bars to view the image. Is there a way to resize/zoom-out the image less or equal to the browser's dimensions?

I've tried wraping the image into a `<div style='max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%'>` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set height and width to 100% to your image.

```
image.height = '100%';
image.width = '100%';
```

Comment: Great! I had to modify my code to dynamically add the style:  `w.document.write("<style>img{max-width: 75%;}</style>", image.outerHTML);`